# How to get Control by coordinates - eclipse platform

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I am looking for method or something in swt (eclipse platform) to get Control when i only have coordinates x and y. 
I found only this

```
Display.getDefault().getCursorControl();
```

but it's not what i am looking for. I want something like that getControlByCoordinates(int x, in y).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method which returns the `Control` by coordinates.

You need to

1. Get the active `Shell`
2. Iterate through all the children (`Control`s) recursively
3. Invoke `getBounds()` on each `Control`
4. Check if your `Point` intersect with the `Rectangle`.